# How to write the following summation in Mathematica?

Tags: summation

How to write the following summation in Mathematica?

[image]

where is n integer.

My try: (But it does not work)

```
Sum[Sum[Subscript[P, i, j]*A[x]^i*B[x]^j, {i+ j, k, n}], {k, 1, n}]
```

After achieving while n is a parameter, can we test it for diverse n values?

Comment: $\sum_k \sum_{i=0}^k F[i, k-i]$ is typically what it means in mathematics. The indices may start at $1$, in which case $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But I did not fully understand. Can you explain more in a new answer by sharing the code?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. What does $\sum_{i+j=k}$ mean exactly to you?

Comment: For example, suppose that n=2. So, in outer summation, k=1  or k=2. For k=1, in interior summation, we have two cases namely {i=1,j=0} and {i=0,j=1}. For k=2, we have three cases, namely, {i=2,j=0} , {i=0,j=2} and {i=1,j=1}.

Comment: So, for instance, $j=k-i$, right? So the sum over $i+j=k$ can be replaced by a sum over $i$, if we replace $j$ by $k-i$ everywhere in the summand?

Comment: What about `Sum[Sum[Subscript[P, i, j]*A[x]^i*B[x]^j, {i, 0, k}, {j, 0, 
   k - i}], {k, 1, n}]` ?

Comment: I would get rid of $j$ in the way I said: `Sum[Sum[Subscript[P, i, k - i]*A[x]^i*B[x]^(k - i), {i, 0, k}], {k, 1, n}]`

Comment: Just checking to be sure that A and B are functions of x and the sum is  raising them to powers, They are not arrays with index i and j. In your code the I and j applied to A and B respectively, are powers and not indices. Not suggesting that's wrong, just verifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sum[Subscript[P, i, k - i]*A[x]^i*B[x]^(k - i), {k, 1, n}, {i, 0, k}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, starting at $k=0$, and substituting `n -> 2`:

```
Sum[Subscript[P, i, k - i]*A[x]^i*B[x]^(k - i),
 {k, 0, n}, {i, 0, k}] /. n -> 2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The sum starting at $k=0$ looks rather like a general polynomial of degree $n$ in two variables $u=A(x)$ and $v=B(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to accomplish it, assuming that $P$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are $n$-component vectors:

```
weirdsum[n_, x_] :=  Sum[P[i, j] A[i, x] B[j, x] KroneckerDelta[i + j, k], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]
```

The `KroneckerDelta` is 1 if both arguments are equal and 0 if they are unequal, so effectively what this does is to sum over all possible values of $i$, $j$, and $k$ and then multiply all the terms for which $i + j \neq k$ by zero.

For example:

```
weirdsum[4, x]

(* A[1, x] B[1, x] P[1, 1] + A[1, x] B[2, x] P[1, 2] + A[1, x] B[3, x] P[1, 3] + 
   A[2, x] B[1, x] P[2, 1] + A[2, x] B[2, x] P[2, 2] + A[3, x] B[1, x] P[3, 1] *)
```

If on the other hand you mean that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are supposed to be raised to the powers of $i$ and $j$, then, replace `A[i, x] B[j, x]` with `A[x]^i B[x]^j` and it should get you what you intended.